# How can I train Artificial Intelligence to understand "laughing"

Tags: azure, artificial-intelligence

I want to write an app that will detect "laughs" differently from conversation/words/etc.

I intend to stream audio or video into a Machine Learning on Azure or Amazon.

Project oxford, Wolfram Aplha, and many others left me lacking in determining what my options are.

**Question**

Is there any way to detect "laughs" within an audio stream?

Answer (score 1):

First thing that comes into my mind would be something like this:

Step 1: create a big (hundrets better thousands) trainingset of audiofiles with the same length. Around 50 % containing laughing, 50% not.

Step 2: Feature engineering: Find features discribing your audiowaves like mean, maxima, minima, standard devation, distribution functions, fourier transformation, ... and so on.

Step 3: Train a classifier (e.g. Decision Tree / SVM / Neural Net) able to seperate your files into 1 (contains laughing) and 0 (does not contain laughing), using these features.

Step 4: Split your stream into parts of the length of your trainingset audiofiles and use your classifier.

You could also check this
http://repository.cmu.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1515&context=compsci

They recognize songs from audiostreams. Sounds a little bit like shazam. The difference here is that they are looking for one specific song and not something so differnetly pronouncable like laughing. But maybe you can adapt some of their algorithms.